# How to use boolean field in form - Python Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django blog, i want to use **Boolean Field** in Form

Here is my Code:

```
class CreateProductForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id': 'ck-editor-area'}))
    excerpt = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'rows': '7'}), required=False)
    price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Amount'}))
    status = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=(('1', 'Active'),('0', 'Inactive'),), attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    quantity = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

I want to change the Status field

```
status = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=(('1', 'Active'),('0', 'Inactive'),), attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

with Boolean Field function (True or False)

What should i do? Thank you

Comment: I can Catch the meaning of your question. can you please, explain what you try to achieve by using the BooleanFIeld ?. is it to update the product status for a vendor  so when the product out of stock the status can be tracked ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pick a certain value to represent `True` and `False` (by using strings), and then "*coerce*" with a function (for example through a *lambda expression*):

```
status = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices=((True, 'Active'), (False, 'Inactive')),
    coerce=lambda x: x == 'True',
)
```

We thus use the values `True` and `False`, and we later use `coerce` to cast the string representation *back* to a valid boolean.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but this is not what I want, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @SulthonMaulanaArrasyid: then you probaby better update the question, and explain what you want in more detail.